# Highcharts Semi Donut Pie with Negative Percentage

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to achieve combined 2 Semidonut Pie Charts series to show Current year and Last year percentage with my data . 
At the same time I am trying to overlay another series with data which will represent the YOY percentage increase or decrease which will appear as label outside my outer pie as "+50%" , "-60%"

Since YOY can be negative and this disturb's the Pie . I was reading that Pie is not ideal to put the negative numbers but visually in my usecase customer feels this will be great .

I tried to massage the YOY data with negative to multiply with (-1) and put into pie and I kind of able to represent the number outside pie but can't bring the "+" or "-" with "%" as valuesuffix .
I have working example here but again this is with 2 data series ... my 3rd series will be "YOY%" with the datalabel display outside which is not added here as 3rd series with negative bring a weird donut .

Anybody has idea how to implement this solution to represent series 3 with YOY Outside as regular datalabels ?

https://codepen.io/pauldx/pen/BayyJaa

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    plotShadow: false
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Browser<br>shares<br>2017',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    y: 60
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        distance: -50,
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: 'white'
        }
      },
      startAngle: -90,
      endAngle: 90,
      center: ['50%', '75%'],
      size: '110%'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    innerSize: '50%',
                dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            // inside: true,
                            distance: -70,
                        },
    data: [
      ['LYA', 58.9],
      ['LYB', 28.9],
      ['LYC', 30.29],

    ]
  },
          {
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    innerSize: '70%',
            dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            // inside: true,
                            distance: -20,
                        },
    data: [
      ['CYA', 20],
      ['CYB', 18.9],
      ['CYC', 70.29],
      ]
  }]
});
```

[image: Pie Chart with Negative]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood - you would like to add only the dataLabels with calculated YOY value, am I right? Or do you want to add a whole series? If just a dataLabels - there is a guideline how to achieve it by adding custom dataLabels:

```
events: {
  render() {
    let chart = this,
      yoyValue,
      x,
      y;

    chart.series[1].points.forEach((p, i) => {

      if (chart['label' + i]) {
        chart['label' + i].destroy();
      }

      yoyValue = Math.floor(((p.y - chart.series[0].points[i].y) / p.y) * 100);
      x = p.dataLabel.translateX - (p.shapeArgs.end == 0 ? -40 : 30);
      y = p.dataLabel.translateY;

      chart['label' + i] = chart.renderer.text(yoyValue + '%', x, y).attr({
        zIndex: 100,
      }).css({
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white',
        textOutline: '1px contrast'
      }).add();
    })
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p82L4ad1/1/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

Comment: Thanks you Sebastian ... Actually I want to add whole series within the same Chart which will nicely label it across each YOY part of it in the pie ... so that YOY will be aligned with CY and LY of each pie .. Is there any easier way to achieve it and keep "+" or "-" with % and possibly a caret symbol with Up and Down arrow

Comment: Could you reproduce it with this third series? Try to do it without negative value and later I will try to edit the dataLabel to show the negative value.

Comment: Hi , I have added this to jfiddle , https://jsfiddle.net/pauldx/r7bd829L/5/  . See how negative numbers screwing up the Semidonut Pie ... Just for your information the YOY in actually completely new dataseries and not calculated based on CY or LY . thanks

Comment: @pauldx - I am not sure if I understood you well... How would you like to show a graphic interpretation of the YOY? For example - I am using this formula to calculate the YOY: ((currentYear - lastYear) / lastYear) - so for the first data it would be (20 - 58.9) / 58.9 = -1.94. And now how this value should be rendered on the pie chart? Because for now, it looks like this (as a positive value) https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3fuLsj95/. We can customize the tooltip and the dataLabels to show this value as a negative, but how the graphic chart interpretation should look like?